# Mousedown on any element with class, affect all elements with different class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this question is confusing – I'm new to JavaScript and struggling with how to even ask this question... this is the desired outcome I came up with:

**When any Foo is mousedown'd on, I want to give all Bars a class, then remove that class when Foo is mouseup'd on.** I'm pretty sure the solution will use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` but that's about as far as I've gotten. Let me know if this needs more clarification and sorry in advance if this is a duplicate.

```html
<div class="foo">When I mousedown/up on this</div>
<div class="foo">When I mousedown/up on this</div>
<div class="bar">Give/remove the 'baz' class to/from this</div>
<div class="bar">Give/remove the 'baz' class to/from this</div>
```

```css
.foo {
  color: blue;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}

.baz {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: can you please add code examples?

Comment: @Itamar updated to include a super simple example of what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dft6oL2/1)

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and `classList.toggle`

HTML

```html
<div class="foo">When I mousedown/up on this</div>
<div class="foo">When I mousedown/up on this</div>
<div class="bar">Give/remove the 'baz' class to/from this</div>
<div class="bar">Give/remove the 'baz' class to/from this</div>
```

EVENTS

```js
function addClass() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.bar').forEach(elm => elm.classList.toggle("baz"))
}

function removeClass() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.bar.baz').forEach(elm => elm.classList.toggle("baz"))
}
```

SUBSCRIBE

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(elm=> {
    elm.onmouseenter = addClass
    elm.onmouseleave = removeClass
})
```

You can even use shorter approach and call the same callback for both (assuming you dont have any other logic in the callbacks

```js
function toggleClass() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.bar').forEach(elm => elm.classList.toggle("baz"))
}


document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(elm=> {
    elm.onmouseenter = toggleClass
    elm.onmouseleave = toggleClass
})
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gL67r2cx/21/)

Comment: ~~This is almost what I need but when I mouseleave the class doesn't seem to be removed until I mouseenter again. I updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkhdesign/zt3axde5/)  to show this a little more clearly~~ I see that you updated your post. Thank you for your help!